# How to decompress LZ4 JSON in Spark 2

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have downloaded a `xxxx.json.lz4` file from `https://censys.io/` however when I try to read the file using the following line I get no data out/count of 0.

```
metadata_lz4 = spark.read.json("s3n://file.json.lz4")
```

it returns no results although decompressing manually works fine and can be imported into Spark.

I have also tried

```
val metadata_lz4_2 = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile("s3n://file.json.lz4", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text])
```

Which also returns no results.

I have multiple of these files which are `100GBs` each so really keen on not having to decompress each one manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: `although decompressing manually works fine`  Could you tell me how to do this manually?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12990) spark LZ4 decompressor uses different specification then the standard LZ4 decompressor.

Hence until this issue will be solved in apache-spark, you won't be able to use spark LZ4 in order to decompress standard LZ4 compressed files.

> I don't think our Lz4Codec implementation actually uses the FRAME
>   specification (http://cyan4973.github.io/lz4/lz4_Frame_format.html)
>   when creating text based files. It seems it was added in as a codec
>   for use inside block compression formats such as
>   SequenceFiles/HFiles/etc., but wasn't oriented towards Text files from
>   the looks of it, or was introduced at a time when there was no FRAME
>   specification of LZ4.
>
> **Therefore, fundamentally, we are not interoperable with the lz4
>   utility.** The difference is very similar to the GPLExtras' LzoCodec vs.
>   LzopCodec, the former is just the data compressing algorithm, but the
>   latter is an actual framed format interoperable with lzop CLI utility.
>
> To make ourselves interoperable, we'll need to introduce a new frame
>   wrapping codec such as LZ4FrameCodec, and users could use that when
>   they want to decompress or compress text data produced/readable by
>   lz4/lz4cat CLI utilities.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved to parse lz4 compression in Pyspark in this way:

```
import lz4.frame
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

list_paths = ['/my/file.json.lz4', '/my/beautiful/file.json.lz4']

rdd = sc.binaryFiles(','.join(list_paths))
df = rdd.map(lambda x: lz4.frame.decompress(x[1])).map(lambda x: str(x)).map(lambda x:  (x, )).toDF()
```

this is usually enough for non complex objects. But if the compressed JSON you are 
 parsing has nested structures, then it is necessary to do extra cleaning on the parsed file before calling the function `F.from_json()`:

```
schema = spark.read.json("/my/uncompressed_file.json").schema

df = df.select(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace("_1", "None", "null"), "False", "false"), "True", "true"), "b'", ""), "'", "").alias("json_notation"))
result_df = df.select(F.from_json("json_notation", schema)
```

where `/my/uncompressed_file.json` is the `/my/file.json.lz4` that you have previously decompressed (unless you want to provide the schema manually if not too complex, it will work anyway)